# How to stop background color of EditTextView in error case in android

Tags: android

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tl_temple_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@android:color/transparent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_temple_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                        android:hint=" Temple Name"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_ligh_grey_bg"
                        android:textColor="@color/brand_color"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is my layout file xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/light_grey"/>
</shape>
```

This is my background of Edit textview

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Error appearance xml file

I am getting proper view when I launch

[image]

but when I getting Error then my Edit text box show

[image]

Can you please tell me how to remove black background from Edit textview

Comment: Can you share the @style/error_appearance code?

Comment: @Top4o I have Edited and added in question can you please check ?

Comment: `<item name="backgroundColor">@color/black</item>` change this from `@style/error_appearance` code to any other color you want to appear in case of error

Comment: after changing this its coming red

Comment: set it to light_grey if you need it to stay light_grey in both cases

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `android:theme=` instead of `app:errorTextAppearance=`

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tl_temple_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
         remove --> app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            add --> android:theme="@style/inputStyle"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@android:color/transparent">
```

And add:

```
<style name="inputStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
   ...
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item> 
   ...
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
   ...
</style>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: when i adding this then Error case text color is coming white while i am expecting red

Comment: Add  <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red</item>

Comment: its not working i tried same still white

Comment: Sorry I got you wrong. Can you try <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item> or <item name="colorError">@color/red</item>. It should be textColor or colorError not the hint.

Comment: after adding this again background coming red of Edit textbox

Comment: its showing error inXML

Answer (score 0):

in `error_appearance` style you have declared `backgroundColor` as `black`. just remove this line or set same color as for background `<shape`